# Crash in getDeclaredAnnotation when using Proguard

Tags: android, jackson, proguard, android-proguard

I have a android app with 10 library projects and one application project.
2 of the library projects are using jackson library as dependencies. Here is the snipet from build.gradle for both of them

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.4'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.4'
```

Now my app crashes with the following exception

> ```
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Native Method) at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveClassAnnotations(AnnotatedClass.java:308)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.getAnnotation(AnnotatedClass.java:173)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.isIgnorableType(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:97)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.isIgnorableType(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:870)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.filterBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:635)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.addBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:527)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:270)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:168)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:399)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:348)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:261)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:241)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:394)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3169)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3033)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1652)
> ```

Prior to crash, I could see the following lines in the log

> ```
> Class resolved by unexpected DEX:
> Lcom/vocalocity/Administration/api/support/extensionKit/ExtkitConfig;(0x41ac7088):0x7acd1000
> ref [Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect$Visibility;]
> Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect$Visibility;(0x41ac7088):0x7a356000
>
> (Lcom/vocalocity/Administration/api/support/extensionKit/ExtkitConfig;
> had used a different
> Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect$Visibility; during
> pre-verification)
>
> Failed processing annotation value
> ```

I have tried building the app without proguard using

```
minifyEnabled = false
```

Then it works fine. But that is not an option as I need to do obfuscation for my app.
I have tried the following in my proguard file.

```
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

But it still gives crash.
Could you please tell me how to avoid this crash?